# Power BI SELECTCOLUMNS Based on Selecter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table

| Column A | Column B | ColumnC | ColumnD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | C1 | D1 |
| A 2 | B2 | C2 | D2 |

Based on a slicer, I wanted to create a new table where ColumnCorD is ColumnC or ColumnD. If the slicer is "ColumnC", the new table is

| Column A | Column B | ColumnCOrD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | C1 |
| A 2 | B2 | C2 |

If the slicer is "ColumnD", the new table is

| Column A | Column B | ColumnCOrD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | D1 |
| A 2 | B2 | D2 |

Is there an easy way to do it with Power BI DAX?

I tried to use `SELECTCOLUMNS` but I do not find a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You were already on the right track. `SELECTCOLUMNS` does exactly, what you requested.

```
DynamicTable = SELECTCOLUMNS(StaticTable, "A", [A], "B", [B], "C or D", [C]&"Or"&[D])
```

[image]

Comment: I updated the initial post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but it is not exactly what I wanted. I wrote a DAX below but when I select the slicer, the data in the new table are not correct.
My DAX:

```html
NewTable = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    MyData,
    "ColA", MyData[ColA],
    "ColB", MyData[ColB], 
     "ColCorD", SWITCH( TRUE(),
              SELECTEDVALUE(SlicerTable[Slicer]) = "ColumnC" , MyData[ColC],
              SELECTEDVALUE(SlicerTable[Slicer]) = "ColumnD" , MyData[ColD],
              "No selection")
)
```

When I click on Slicer C, I expect the values for ColCorD to be the values from ColC.
When I click on Slicer D, I expect the values for ColCorD to be the values from ColD.

Comment: Data in a calculated table in the data-model will only recalculate when you load or refresh your model. It will not react to the change of a slicer on a reportpage.